# Checkpointing on Spark Node failures

Tags: spark-streaming, checkpointing

I have developed a Spark Streaming application (which has internal sates as well) with check pointing and fault-tolerant..This is working on when I exit my application and re-reun it...so every thing (states..) loads well,

I wonder why in the case of cluster miss, should it work or not? because I guess Spark save checkpoints as pointers to memory location...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work, as after cluster up, the state is regained.